# Nvidia 9600GT RFRemix 28

Tags: linux, fedora, nvidia

Вчера поставил **28** Руссиан Федору на другой винт. Установил

```
kmod
akmod-nvidia
```

Все поставилось без проблем, но при загрузке получаю сообщение типа

```
Unable load NVIDIA kernel module
Fail back to nouveau
```

**Вывод dmesg:**

```
]$ dmesg | grep -i NVIDIA
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-4.16.14-300.fc28.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/rfremix_fedora-root ro resume=/dev/mapper/rfremix_fedora-swap rd.lvm.lv=rfremix_fedora/root rd.lvm.lv=rfremix_fedora/swap rhgb quiet rd.driver.blacklist=nouveau modprobe.blacklist=nouveau nvidia-drm.modeset=1
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-4.16.14-300.fc28.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/rfremix_fedora-root ro resume=/dev/mapper/rfremix_fedora-swap rd.lvm.lv=rfremix_fedora/root rd.lvm.lv=rfremix_fedora/swap rhgb quiet rd.driver.blacklist=nouveau modprobe.blacklist=nouveau nvidia-drm.modeset=1
[   16.642476] nvidia: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[   16.642488] nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
[   16.652981] nvidia: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[   16.663395] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 242
[   16.663619] NVRM: The NVIDIA GeForce 9600 GT GPU installed in this system is
               NVRM:  supported through the NVIDIA 340.xx Legacy drivers. Please
               NVRM:  visit http://www.nvidia.com/object/unix.html for more
               NVRM:  information.  The 390.59 NVIDIA driver will ignore
[   16.663624] NVRM: No NVIDIA graphics adapter found!
[   16.663704] nvidia-nvlink: Unregistered the Nvlink Core, major device number 242
[   16.721500] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 242
[   16.721834] NVRM: The NVIDIA GeForce 9600 GT GPU installed in this system is
               NVRM:  supported through the NVIDIA 340.xx Legacy drivers. Please
               NVRM:  visit http://www.nvidia.com/object/unix.html for more
               NVRM:  information.  The 390.59 NVIDIA driver will ignore
[   16.721840] NVRM: No NVIDIA graphics adapter found!
[   16.721923] nvidia-nvlink: Unregistered the Nvlink Core, major device number 242
[   34.112001] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: NVIDIA G94 (094100a1)
[   39.638576] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 242
[   39.638920] NVRM: The NVIDIA GeForce 9600 GT GPU installed in this system is
               NVRM:  supported through the NVIDIA 340.xx Legacy drivers. Please
               NVRM:  visit http://www.nvidia.com/object/unix.html for more
               NVRM:  information.  The 390.59 NVIDIA driver will ignore
[   39.638925] NVRM: No NVIDIA graphics adapter found!
[   39.639027] nvidia-nvlink: Unregistered the Nvlink Core, major device number 242
[   45.626363] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 242
[   45.626666] NVRM: The NVIDIA GeForce 9600 GT GPU installed in this system is
               NVRM:  supported through the NVIDIA 340.xx Legacy drivers. Please
               NVRM:  visit http://www.nvidia.com/object/unix.html for more
               NVRM:  information.  The 390.59 NVIDIA driver will ignore
[   45.626671] NVRM: No NVIDIA graphics adapter found!
[   45.626757] nvidia-nvlink: Unregistered the Nvlink Core, major device number 242
```

Под **27** все работает. Правда там ставился драйвер на 23 и постепенными обновлениями дошло до 27. И была возможность выбора версии драйвера 304 или 340 (для старых и новых видеокарт), а теперь такого нет.
Кажется мне, что карточка больше не поддерживается.

Есть ли возможность запустить проприентарные дрова на 28? Это нужно, так как Blender не очень-то стабилен на nouveau.

ПС. К теме не относится, по в ближайшее время планирую прикупить 650Ti. Может не заморачиавтся и посидеть пока на 27?

Comment: [Связанный вопрос](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/120854/where-is-xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-340xx-fore-fedora-28/). В багзилле пишут, что можно ручками установить пакет из **f27**.

Comment: Ладно, сегодня закажу GTX650. Всё-равно собирался. Если загрузиться, думаю, что можно списать на Deprecated моей видеокарты.

Comment: дык, про это же прямым текстом в сообщениях ядра написано ­— установлены 390-е дрова, но поддержка 9600 серии кончилась на 340. А пакет со старыми дровами под новую федору не могут запилить т.к. нет человека, который взялся бы его поддерживать...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, да наверное и смысла-то особого нет... Видеокарта-то старая.
ПС. Если воткнуть 650Ти, заработает без танцев с бубном (установкой переустановкой и т.д.?)

Comment: Должно без проблем... разве что `xorg.conf` снести/подправить нужно будет, если используется... обычно основная проблема при покупке новой видюхи — это крайне тяжёлые переговоры с жабой =)

Answer (score 0):

NVidia драйвер не дружит с nouveau, если устанавливал nvidia вручную, то вручную удали nouveau запихни его в чёрный список

```
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf :
...
blacklist nouveau
...
```

Если никак, по-новой установи nvidia драйвер.

Comment: вопрос совсем не про то...